# "Product by company" or "product from company"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Suppose that there is a company named Megasoft. Megasoft has just launched their new software application to the public called Softronic.
Which is correct: *Softronic by Megasoft* or *Softronic from Megasoft*?

Comment: What about *Megasoft Softronic*? :)

Comment: Why would one be incorrect? They are both correct.

Answer (score 2):

Both are fine.

> Softronic by Megasoft

This implies that Megasoft made Softronic.

> Softronic from Megasoft

This only tells you that Megasoft is the source. They might have made it, or they might just be the distributors.

I said *implies*, but bear in mind that salespeople often imply things that aren't true.